# There’s no standard specification for JavaScript's backend APIs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webapi, deno, web-standards

I’m writing an article on JavaScript and a question came up.

JavaScript has [Web APIs](https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/script) as its standard specification **for the browser**.

There’s no standard specification for JavaScript's backend (Node and Deno) APIs?

Comment: Do these count: [node.js API documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/) / [Deno  CLI APis](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable)

Comment: I suspect there's no (need for a) "standards" spec for these because they are single applications.  They're not something that's used by multiple applications in the way that javascript is used by browsers/node/etc.

Comment: All of those APIs, front-end and back-end, are *not part of JavaScript*. They do support JavaScript programming, but there are many different "back ends" in this world, with different needs.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have Web APIs. Web browsers have JavaScript Web APIs.

From [JavaScript - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript):

> JavaScript is a high-level, often just-in-time compiled language that conforms to the ECMAScript standard.[14] It has dynamic typing, prototype-based object-orientation, and first-class functions. It is multi-paradigm, supporting event-driven, functional, and imperative programming styles. It has application programming interfaces (APIs) for working with text, dates, regular expressions, standard data structures, and the Document Object Model (DOM).
>
> The ECMAScript standard does not include any input/output (I/O), such as networking, storage, or graphics facilities. In practice, the web browser or other runtime system provides JavaScript APIs for I/O.

Web browsers have APIs for the web exposed via JavaScript. JavaScript does not have Web APIs, or any I/O itself. Node.js and Deno, like a web browser, expose various JavaScript APIs to developers to build upon for their use cases. Many of these APIs are the same Web APIs that web browsers implement while some are not.

Node.js and Deno implement some of the same Web APIs but also have various APIs specific to their platforms.

> There’s no standard specification for JavaScript's backend (Node and Deno) APIs?

Correct. There is not currently. At least not one that Node.js and Deno adhere to.